# GZip is not working regularly on IIS 8.5 godaddy windows shared hosting

Tags: gzip, iis-8

The problem is when i recycle app pool Gzip works, but after 2-3 minutes it again starts showing Gzip is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure enable Gzip compression in ASP.NET using web.config configuration.

I have tried it on GoDaddy’s Windows Shared Hosting and it works fine.

```
<system.webServer>
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
    <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>
    <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
    </dynamicTypes>
    <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
    </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```